# Storing values from a recursive function call

Tags: python, recursion

I am calling a function `obtainingparams` recursively and require that the value for `residuals`, `tau_1` and `tau_2`, in the code below, from each call is stored somewhere, so that I can then compare the values associated with each call to the function. However, I am not too sure how to go about doing this.

```
def obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals):
    print('Calculate the yields Matrix and matrix_of_params in this part')

    params = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix_of_params,yields) 
    residuals = np.sqrt(((yields - matrix_of_params.dot(params))**2).sum())  
    tau_1 = tau_1 + 0.2 
    tau_2 = tau_2 + 0.2

    #Checkin how many times the function has been called via a decorator not included in this code
    while self.obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals).called < 5:
        self.obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this is a slightly messy way by using a global list. The arguments to the first call will be in values[0], the second call in values[1], etc.

```
values = []

def obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals):
    global values

    print('Calculate the yields Matrix and matrix_of_params in this part')

    params = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix_of_params,yields) 
    residuals = np.sqrt(((yields - matrix_of_params.dot(params))**2).sum())  
    tau_1 = tau_1 + 0.2 
    tau_2 = tau_2 + 0.2

    values.append((tau1, tau2, residuals))

    #Checkin how many times the function has been called via a decorator not included in this code
    while self.obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals).called < 5:
        self.obtainingparams(self, df, tau_1, tau_2, residuals)
```

From a design perspective, I'm not sure if using recursion is the best here if you really want to keep track of the parameters used with each call.

Comment: How could I do this, if I didn't want to use recursion?

Comment: I would probably have `obtainingparams` return `tau_1`, `tau_2`, and `residuals` and then call it in a loop.  You would still need a list to keep track of the parameters used each time Each iteration of the loop, you would call `obtainingparams` with the last item in the list. The way you're doing it now is perfectly good, but you're not getting much benefit from recursion.